# Showing one div by hovering over another with css

Tags: html, css

I would like to make a drop-down menu but whenever I find them online they are so confusing, I thought I had it but it doesn't work what have I done wrong here:

css:

```
.dropDownContents{
    display:none;
    }
.dropdown:hover .dropDownContents{
    color:white;
    background-color:black;
    border:solid 1px white;
    vidibility: visible;
    display: block;
```

And the html:

```
<div class = "dropDownbtn">
    <button class = "dropdown">H1</button>
    <a href = "" class = "dropDownContents">P1</a>
    <a href = "" class = "dropDownContents">P2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: It's `visibility` not `vidibility`. But it makes no sense to use visibility anyway since you're changing the display property. You're also missing a closing `}`

Comment: My pure-CSS drop-down menus are organized as `ul` with `li` and `li > ul` children, all within a `<div id="menu" role="menubar">` ... so my CSS is all about `#menu` with `#menu ul > li` and `:hover` rules, so things like `#menu ul li` and `#menu ul ul` etc. I have things like `#menu > ul > li:hover { display: block; }` where otherwise, without hover, they are `display: none;`.  My actual menu picks are `<a>` as you have. You shouldn't have to put classes on everything; it is the top-level class (or id) that says the thing is a menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, in your example elements with `.dropDownContents` are not descendants of `.dropdown` - they're its siblings. So the selector should be changed accordingly:

```css
.dropDownContents{
    display:none;
}
.dropdown:hover ~ .dropDownContents{
    color:white;
    background-color:black;
    border:solid 1px white;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropDownbtn">
    <button class="dropdown">H1</button>
    <a href="" class="dropDownContents">P1</a>
    <a href="" class="dropDownContents">P2</a>
</div>
```

It's not that simple, however: as long as you hover over any of those `a` elements, they disappear - as the pointer moves out from the button, and its `hover` state is dropped.

That's why most of the time dropdown menus are implemented as descendants (children usually) of the element triggering its appearance:

```css
.dropDownContents{
    display:none;
}
.dropDownbtn:hover .dropDownContents{
    color:white;
    background-color:black;
    border:solid 1px white;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropDownbtn">
    <button>H1</button>
    <a href="" class="dropDownContents">P1</a>
    <a href="" class="dropDownContents">P2</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This drop down menu works using CSS. I just included it  on the page and would give credit where I found it - but have long since  lost that page.

Also my Drop Down Menu would not work once I published to the website until I turn Compatibility Mode OFF(Yes we are required to use IE and have no control over that decision):

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen"> 
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

 .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 }

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
   }

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
 }

 .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

    </style>
```

The DROP DOWN MENU:

```
<h2>Dropdown Menu</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="dropdown" >
  <button class="dropbtn">Admin</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">@Html.ActionLink("Re Names", "Index", "MTS_RENAME")</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown2</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>
    <a href="#">Link 5</a>
    <a href="#">Link 6</a>
  </div>
</div>
```